# Travelling visa

Tags: refugees

I am a Somalian  who was a refugee last 10 years in South Africa. I never get chance to travel. But  they gave me (UNlP Travel document wich is UN Lezzer Passport) so my question is:

Can I get free Visa  for Canada or Australia. And  stay those country  like  a refugee.

Comment: Your question appears to be about immigrating to Canada or Australia, so it is off topic on this site.  You may want to ask at [Expatriates.SE], where it is on topic.

Comment: You mean a laissez-passer? That would imply you work for the UN but still won't allow you to live in any country you choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your last question is **no**. South Africa gave you safety from the danger and persecution in Somalia, so Canada and Australia would most likely send you back to South Africa.

You may be able to get a Canadian or Australian tourist visa, but to do so you must convince them that you are a *real* tourist. That requires a stable job and ties to your place of residence.